# Why do we use `$` in a script?

Tags: bash

A guy displayed the following script :

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter a directory: " dir
start=$(date)
echo "Document directory usage report" > /tmp/report
du -sh $dir >> /tmp/report
echo "Start of report: $start" >> /tmp/report
echo "End of report: $(date)" >> /tmp/report
```

Could anyone be able to tell me why we use `$` in the command `echo "Start of report : $start"` ?

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984958/what-does-it-mean-in-shell-when-we-put-a-command-inside-dollar-sign-and-parenthe, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48106/what-does-it-mean-to-have-a-dollarsign-prefixed-string-in-a-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could anyone be able to tell me why we use $ in the command echo "Start of report : $start" ?

It is a bash (and sh) feature. The text `"$start"` is replaced with the value of the variable called `"start"`. In your script, the `start` variable is set to the output of the `date` command by the line `start=$(date)`. Note that `$(...)` is a different shell feature from `$...`.

For more complete information on the bash scripting language, see:

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/